# second part of a list with something like BinLists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list that looks like this

```
testList = 
  Transpose@Table[{RandomInteger[{0, 100}], RandomReal[]}, {100}];
```

i.e. basically two lists in one. Using BinLists I can bin the values of e.g. the first list.

```
 BinLists[testList[[1]], {0, 100, 10}]
```

However, I would like to have the values of the second list in the resulting bin list that correspond to the values of the first list.
I hope I make myself clear, otherwise I can make it more clear.
I have a solution with a loop which is taking ages, as it is a very large dataset.
Thanks!

Comment: Are the binned values  (`RandomInteger[{0, 100}]` in the example) guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: No, that's the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this does what you want.  (Note the absence of `Transpose` before `Table`.)

```
SeedRandom[1];

testList = Table[{RandomInteger[{0, 100}], RandomReal[]}, {100}];

BinLists[testList, {0, 100, 10}, {0, 1, 1}][[All, 1]]
```

The second bin specification `{0, 1, 1}` simply puts all *y* values in a single bin, since they all fall in the interval [0, 1].

By the way, sometimes it is both easier an more efficient to roll your own.  This is nearly equivalent for the given example and several times faster:

```
GatherBy[testList, Floor[#[[1]], 10] &] ~SortBy~ First
```

Comment: Great thanks. Looks good. I have to understand your second approach, though.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, is it possible to apply similar task, but for bining (or Gathering) in arbitrarily bin widths: eg binning `testList2={{"1A",1},{"2A",2}, {"170A",170},{"3A",3}, {"90A",90},{"80A",80},{"2A",2},{"110A",110},{"222A",222},{"200A",200},{"215A",215},{"30A",30}}` into `bins={{0,20,100,\[Infinity]}}` according to 2nd element in sublists as bin criterion?

Comment: @Dragutin I saw your new question and posted an answer.